# Find out the current version of mySQL using either PHP or SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Using either a SQL query, or some php code, how can I determine which version of MySQL is running.
I found several examples of using the command line, but I need to check programmatically.

I tried

```
SELECT @version;
```

But that returned NULL.

I did search stack overflow, and found a lot of questions, but they were about other dbs or programming languages. I didn't find any specifically for MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get by user [mysqli_server_info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-server-info.php) or the oop way using `$mysqli->server_info;`

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* print server version */
printf("MYSQL Server version: %s\n", $mysqli->server_info);

$mysqli->close();
```

Or in MYSQL Query way

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

Or you may want to show in detailed way

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax with mysql is `select version();`

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3bbebf7efe9f01901d41d4013bf96b4c)